# Problem with 'time dependent' functions

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I'm just trying to make $\frac{dx}{dt}$ where $x= \rho  \cos\theta \sin\phi$ where $\theta, \phi $ and $\rho$ are time dependent functions.

```
r = r[t];

th = th[t];

phi = phi[t];

x = r*Cos[phi]*Sin[th];

D[x, t].
```

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest that: 1) You take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now! 2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)! 3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.

Comment: Thank you! I'll do that right now! Is my post that bad?

Comment: No, It is just good practice.  Also, your first three lines should be deleted.

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
ClearAll[r, phi, th]
x = r[t]*Cos[phi[t]]*Sin[th[t]]; D[x, t]

(* -r[t] Sin[phi[t]] Sin[th[t]] Derivative[1][phi][t] + 
 Cos[phi[t]] Sin[th[t]] Derivative[1][r][t] + 
 Cos[phi[t]] Cos[th[t]] r[t] Derivative[1][th][t] *)
```

Expressions like

```
r = r[t];
```

can lead to infinite recursions.

Comment: `Dt[]` would also be appropriate here, methinks.

Comment: @Guesswhoitis.  Indeed, `Dt[r*Cos[phi]*Sin[th], t]` is compact and effective.  Thanks.